# Solving a boolean expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve the following Boolean expression:

$$a + \neg{a} b + \neg{a} \neg b c + \neg a \neg b \neg c d + \dots$$

The question asked was to use Boolean algebra in order to solve the above expression.

My attempt so far:

$$y = a + \neg a b + \neg a \neg b c + \neg a \neg b \neg c d = a + \neg a y$$

This does not look meaningful to me.

Comment: In java or many other programming languages, this would be an iterated "if-then-else". I It was possible to *solve* that, IT-business would look quite a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that p + ¬pq =p + q.
Then a + ¬ab = a + b by letting p= a and q=b.

Now let p = a+b and q = c to get 
a + ¬ab + ¬a¬bc = a + b + c since ¬p = ¬a¬b by De Morgan.
Continue inductively.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is an infinite Boolean expression. Regardless of that, some natural-language reasoning tells us it should simplify to $a + b + c + d + \dots$.

("This dog is either a black lab, or not a black lab and a golden retriever, or not a black lab and not a golden retriever but a Pomeranian, or ..." is a verbose way of saying that you know nothing about this dog.)

Comment: I'm working on how to show this algebraically. Neat puzzle! Really, we should also have: $y = b + \neg b a + \neg a \neg b c + \dots$, or any reshuffling, shouldn't we?

Answer (score 0):

Writing $a_k$ instead of $a,b,c,\dots$ and shorter $\bar a$ instead of $\neg a$, we have $y_n=a_n+\bar a_ny_{n+1}$. Plugging in values for $a_n$ we get $y_n=a_n+y_{n+1}$. So for fixed $N$ we have $y_0=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n+y_N$.